# How is it possible to edit video duration on an mp4?

Tags: video, metadata, mp4, hex-editor

I recently came across a few videos that have their duration length edited. Some increase as the video is playing; for example when you start the video the duration reads `0:01/0:02`, and as the video goes on both increase. `0:02/0:03`, etc.

Some videos just read the duration as `900:00:01/12:07`.

-Note:
I don't know anything about hex or metadata editing. Just very curious to how someone can make video duration increase as the video plays.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvRc7.png

Comment: are these files you've downloaded or are these videos you're playing over the internet? If the latter, it could very well be a live stream

Comment: Downloaded, not streamed. Sent though discord.